# Magento: Advanced Search to Show Bundle Products

Tags: magento, bundle, advanced-search

I would like to be able to show Bundle Products on my Advanced Search result even if the searched attribute criteria is blank (not set) in the actual Bundle Product. For example:

**I have 3 Simple Products:**

Brand: Acme

Color: Green

**And 1 Bundle Product:**

Brand: Acme

Color: *--blank--*

Associated Products: the 3 products above.

My current Advanced Search Result is 3 Simple Products, but how can I also have the  Bundle Product show up in my results even-thought the Color attribute is blank? Since the "child" products have the Color listed, I think it should also appear in search results, it does on the Layered Navigation.